# Is there any possible way to take image option from R.drawable. instead of my xml file?

Tags: android, drawable

i am working on a flipper image and in this app image is taking from xml file, i want to take image from R.drawable recourse folder and also in this app has to button "Play" and "Pause" that are working from xml, is there any way to make this slide show from resource folder? Any help will be appreciated.

My java code:

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;   
private AnimationListener mAnimationListener;
private Context mContext;
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  private final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 mContext = this;
 mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
 mViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
 public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

 findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //sets auto flipping
        mViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        mViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
        mViewFlipper.startFlipping();
    }
});

findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //stop auto flipping 
        mViewFlipper.stopFlipping();
    }
});


//animation listener
mAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        //animation started event
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //TODO animation stopped event
    }
 };
}
   class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
  @Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    try {
        // right to left swipe
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.left_in));
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.left_out));
            // controlling animation
            mViewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
            mViewFlipper.showNext();
            return true;
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.right_in));
            mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.right_out));
            // controlling animation
            mViewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
            mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            return true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
  }
 }
}
```

My XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewFlipper
android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/p1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/ImageTitle"
        android:text="@string/text1" />
</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/p2" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ImageTitle"
        android:text="@string/text2" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/p3" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/ImageTitle"
        android:text="@string/text3" />
  </RelativeLayout>
 </ViewFlipper>

  <LinearLayout
style="@style/ButtonContainer"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/swipe_left"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:src="@drawable/back" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/swipe_right"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:src="@drawable/next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean "image is taking from xml file" ? Can you provide more details. The Drawables what you have set for ImageView in Xml are from Drawables only. R.drawable refers to the same Drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

i think i could do something like this:

```
public class Level1ScreenView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

SurfaceHolder holder;
Bitmap flipper2;
Paint paint = new Paint();

public Level1ScreenView(Context context){
super(context);




    flipper2= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.p2); 





    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){


            canvas.drawBitmap(flipper2, 0, 0, paint);  // first 0 is x, second 0 is y
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    public void run() {
        while (ok == true){
            //perform canvas drawing
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){//if surface is not valid
                continue;//skip anything below it
            }


            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(); //Lock canvas, paint canvas, unlock canvas
            this.onDraw(c);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);}

}}
```

by the way, programmatic or by xml, the images are coming from the same folder drawable.

Comment: You can check my XML, i have 3 ImageView but i want to take my images from java code not from XML.